# Syntax error,unexpected T_BOOLEAN_OR

Tags: php, session

help me with this..kindly stuck on this for hours

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || $_SESSION['user_type'] !='admin')||(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || $_SESSION['user_type'] !='user'){ // if session variable "username" does not exist.
header("location:index.php?msg=Sila%20log%20masuk%20untuk%20mengakses&type=error");
```

}

When I logged in as admin, it was working. But it keep show me this error when I logged as user

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_OR in C:\xampp\htdocs\cubaan\init.php on line 4

Can you guys help me with this

Comment: You are closing the `if (` bracket before your second `||`. Move that bracket to the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it
`<?php 
if((!isset($_SESSION['username']) || $_SESSION['user_type'] !='admin')||(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || $_SESSION['user_type'] !='user')){ // if session variable "username" does not exist.
}
header("location:index.php?msg=Sila%20log%20masuk%20untuk%20mengakses&type=error");
?>`

Comment: done already but still not working..thanks by the way